# How to initialize static const char* enum type traits array?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I've encountered a header in an external sdk like so:

```
// external.h
//
template <class T> class MyBaseEnum
{
public: 
    /** String list. */
    static const char *mStrings[];

    //! Constructor.
    inline MyBaseEnum(){}  

    //! Destructor.
    inline ~MyBaseEnum()
    {

    }
};
```

I've seen this class used in the same sdk in another header like so:

```
// foo.h
//
class Foo
{
    enum MyEnum 
    {
        A = 0,
        B,
        C
    };
    typedef MyBaseEnum< MyEnum > MyEnumType;

    MyEnumType bar;
};
```

I don't have access to the corresponding cpp file to see how `mStrings` is initialized for bar, but I think this is related to type traits.

What would the syntax look like in `foo.cpp` to correctly initialize `MyEnumType::mStrings`?

Answer (score 1):

As `MyBaseEnum` is a templated class, the `mStrings` member *can't* be defined in a separate source file. It has to be done in a header file that is included, as the definition requires the template argument.

The syntax is basically the same as defining any other string array:

```
template<class T>
const char* MyBaseEnum<T>::mStrings = { ... };
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I can actually define `mStrings` in foo.cpp like so: `template <> const char* MyBaseEnum< MyEnum >::mStrings[] = {"A", "B", "C"};` or `template <> const char* Foo::MyEnumType::mStrings[]` but why would foo.h declare `MyEnumType bar;`

Comment: @PeterMcG Does `MyBaseEnum` contain any non-static member functions than the ones you shown? Then that may be a reason. Otherwise you have to ask the author who added the `bar` member variable in `Foo` for the reason.